# Can I have all of my unit tests run in the Flask app context?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

For every test I write that uses my apps models, I seem to have to use the current apps context:

```
SomeTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        ...

    test_something(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            # Do something
```

Is there a way to tell all of my tests to run using the current apps context to save me having this line in all of my tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for by looking at the [way the Flask-Testing extensions TestCase sets itself up](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/blob/master/flask_testing/utils.py#L91), i.e., pushing the testing context to the `_ctx` stack inside a function that's called from within it's `__call__` method.

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    def __call__(self, result=None):
        try:
            self._pre_setup()
            super(BaseTestCase, self).__call__(result)
        finally:
            self._post_teardown()

    def _pre_setup(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self._ctx = self.app.test_request_context()
        self._ctx.push()

    def _post_teardown(self):
        if getattr(self, '_ctx') and self._ctx is not None:
            self._ctx.pop()
        del self._ctx
```

And my test:

```
class SomeTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    test_something(self):
        # Test something - we're using the right app context here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below.

DISCLAIMER: I just came up with the idea and didn't test this solution thoroughly although it seems to work. It is also IMHO rather ugly.

```
from functools import wraps

def with_context(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def _with_context(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            test(self)
    return _with_context


SomeTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        ...

    @with_context
    test_something(self):
        # Do something
```

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks for your answer. Not quite what I'm looking for, though. Maybe I need to go and learn more about the app context and what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you test you may be able to use the [test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.test_client). Example:

```
SomeTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.client = self.app.text_client()

    test_something(self):
        response = self.client.get('/something')
        # check response
```

Comment: Yeah I use the test client in my functional tests (i.e., all the tests that physically hit the route to make sure it's doing what it should), but I don't want to use the test client in any of my unit tests.